# Creating tests to ensure I can't ever modify a struct definition in rust

Tags: testing, rust

I am building a system that will have versioned structs. So anytime a field in a struct changes or we add or remove fields we have to create a new struct.

```
struct MyStruct1 {
    a: usize
}
```

so when `a` changes I have to create

```
struct MyStruct2 {
    a: i32
}
```

Is there a way I can create tests to ensure a developer doesn't accidentally change the field definition on `MyStruct1` instead of creating `MyStruct2`?

I thought about using the serialised struct data and creating a test that tests whether it can be deserialised into a `MyStruct1`, but as there are types that will be serialised indistinguishably from each other that won't work.

Also it needs to work with changes in nested structures:

```
struct MyStruct1 {
    b: NestedStruct
}

struct NestedStruct {
    b: usize,
    c: String,
}
```

so if field `c` was changed the test on `MyStruct1` would fail.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: What would you use as a baseline to find out what changes were made in a type definition? How do you keep track of this? Is the crate given new versions every time?

Comment: Code reviews and approvals are good tests for this kind. You cannot automate anything. -- Unit tests will break on incompatible changes, too. Changing the tests together with the implementation will be intention.

Comment: Using static code analyzers can be a good idea to automate this process, you'll have complete control like designing custom versioning rules for your structs, only thing in here you need to know when the comparing will happen and against what?(as it is mentioned in the first comment.)

Comment: Yes I guess the baseline would be the last version of the crate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd try using https://crates.io/crates/semverver

Changing a public struct is a backward incompatible change, so requires a major version bump, adding a new struct is a backward compatible change, so only requires a minor version bump. So you can use that tool to compare the exposed interface to previous release and check it does not require a major version bump.

In fact I really expect a policy like this to be part of a more general rule to only make backward compatible changes, and that's the tool to check that.